# Android FragmentTabHost Switching

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentTabhost with two tabs in which both tabs fetch data from the internet, when i switch between the tabs previously loaded data are reloaded, i saw the response in this 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423873/avoid-reloading-data-in-fragmenttabhost-tab-switching) but that didnt seem to answer my problem. Although have tried passing data in previous activities using bundle like this

```
private void prepareBundle() {
        Log.d("BUNDLE", "Bundle Rebuiled");
        bundles = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
        ArrayList<ListData> classData = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        classData.add(new ListData("J.S.S.2A", 1));
        classData.add(new ListData("J.S.S.3A", 12));
        classData.add(new ListData("J.S.S.2B", 7));
        Bundle classes = new Bundle();
        classes.putParcelableArrayList("classData", classData);


        ArrayList<ListData> subject = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        subject.add(new ListData("Mathematics - J.S.S.1A", 1, 11));
        subject.add(new ListData("Mathematics - J.S.S.1B", 4, 21));
        subject.add(new ListData("Mathematics - J.S.S.2B", 6, 41));
        subject.add(new ListData("Mathematics - J.S.S.2A", 8, 13));
        Bundle subjects = new Bundle();
        subjects.putParcelableArrayList("subjectData", subject);


        bundles.add(classes);
        bundles.add(subjects);
        bundles.add(null);
    }
```

and apply in the tab like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < MENUCLASSES.length; i++) {
            Class currentClass = Class.forName(Utilities.PACKAGE + "."
                    + MENUCLASSES[i]);
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    setTabSpecs(this, mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAGS[i]),
                            R.drawable.ic_bk, menuText[i],
                            icon.getResourceId(i, -1)), currentClass, bundles.get(i));
        }
```

But this next activity has Fragments that uses complex data strutures that i can't pass using bundle as one of the fragment is plotting graph.
My question is how can i prevent the tab from reloading data from the internet if the data has been previously fetched. Thanks

Comment: Are you using view pager with FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: No am not using view pager just FragmentTabhost and a Fragment serving as a container

Comment: What you can do is save some variable in Shared Preferences like `dataFetched=true` when first time data was loaded.Then every time pass this value in bundle when your going to apply in the tab. In the Fragment oncreate  or onresume method check whether the data is fetched or not. If not then load from the internet.

Comment: @HordedoyinMatthewg you can call the API's in Activity and use in fragments.